# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: database "db_name" does not exist on EC2 amazon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am using capistrano for rails application deployment. But i'm facing `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "db_name" does not exist` error.

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that there is no database exist with the name "db_name".

You need to create the database on EC2 server and use the name and password of that database into your config/database.yml file in the production block.

Alternatively, you can run

```
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

on the EC2 server, so it will create a database with specified configuration of database.yml file. Once the database gets created you will no longer get this error.